# Freezing the Contents of a UIScrollView while updating

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIView with a CATiledLayer visible within a UIScrollView.

At certain times I need to relocate the window contents relative to the scroll view origin.

I need to change the contentOffset property of the scroll view but, when I redraw, the contents are the same.

The sequence is

```
scrollView.contentOffset = newoffset ;
[contentView setNeedsDisplay]
```

This creates a jerky effect as the scrollView shifts.

Is there any way to freeze the visible area of the scroll view until the drawing is complete?

Essentially, I'd like to

[FREEZE DISPLAY]
    scrollView.contentOffset = newoffset ; // But have no visible change
    [contentView setNeedsDisplay]
   [UNFREEZE DISPLAY AFTER a SHORT DELAY]

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing that in your delegate methods of `UIScrollView`. It has a very specific set of methods that you can use to time your update appropriately.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Between these 3 methods, I'm sure that one of these is going to make that call with the timing that you're looking for.

Last thing, watch out for how many times your calling the `setNeedsDisplay` method when utilizing these delegates. `setNeedsDisplay` isn't cheap on memory if you're calling it every millisecond!

Cheers

Comment: The redraw is triggered in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating or scrollViewDidEndDragging if there is no deceleration. I still have not gotten the thing to freeze yet.